# Complex db Queries in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do an oddball type of query to a database that I cannot seem to figure out how to do.

I made a sample database, shown below, just for this question, as I cannot display the real database because of its proprietary nature.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGDaQ.png

My goal is to be able to add an order and order items on the same page, while displaying a list of the products as shown below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLMrB.jpg

Not every order will contain all of the products, but I still need to be able to list all of the products and have the ability to enter a quantity if there is one.  How would I go about laying this out using MVC?  Currently, I am using a ViewModel inside the Create View for the Orders to display the ProductName list. I cannot seem to figure out how to get boxes that would allow me to add in the OrderItems information for each product name.

Comment: I'm on my phone so sorry for the brief answer until I get back to computer but you can form.serialize and send to server and it will populate your object model. You will just have to name your Ids on the page so it binds your child order items. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx